# Django 404 via wsgi.py

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm using a baremetal server on scaleway and I'm trying to write the first django app from django tutorial.

Since I'm using a remote server I can't use `manage.py startserver` than i trying to use wsgi.py.

this is my apache conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /test-app /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/testApp/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/django-apps/testApp

<Directory /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/testApp>
<Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

the project it's been created with django-admin as the example.
If I use `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000` from console, I can see "It worked! Congratulations...".

I added the server IP (and 127.0.0.1) to ALLOWED_HOST, as suggested the first time I tried to browse `http://myserverip/test-app`

Now curl to loopback still work, but the browser via public IP report:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://mypublicip/test-app/

Using the URLconf defined in testApp.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Any suggestion?
thanks.

---

@Laurynas Tamulevičius:

TestApp -> urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I don't understand why the generated html differs from runserver to wsgi.

---

### Update:

Searching the web, seems that `manage.py startserver` automagically create some alias for the correct management of the script and the code.
One alias should be `/static/` that points to a particular directory under django installation. Other alias cold be created in same way.

Thats in my opinion is a simple way for dummies, but is a perver system to understand what is need to deploy a django site.

---

### Update 2:

@Graham Dumpleton
Yes. With `http://mypublicip/test-app/admin` i can see the administration login page without css. I suppose that for css the `/static/` Alias for django administration is needed.

If I hunderstand, I need to add the handle for `/`. 
How I can do that? Adding something in `testApp.urls` ?

Why is not needed when I use runserver? Or is the "It worked! Congratulations..." page that is visible only using runserver?

---

### Update 3:

**OK! I achieved a first result!
Now for the admin page, the css are loaded.**

I added/modified some lines to settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/test-app/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/test-app/media/'
```

then run the command `python3 manage.py collectstatic`. The command created in BASE_DIR the directory *static*, with all the required static files.

then added to the apache2 configuration file some lines thats instruct apache2 to know the aliases for  STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL and to allow apache2 to reach the directories.

```
#static files
Alias /test-app/media/ /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/media/
Alias /test-app/static/ /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/static/

<Directory /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/django-apps/testApp/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

At this point I wonder: the default page "It work ..." displayed by django runserver, is a automatic redirection of the 404 page, make by runserver?

I expected to see a pege "It work ..." also in wsgi configuration, but maybe I was in wrong. 
Deploying the site needs that all the site are really work with the default page and the redirection for `/`.

I can continue to work now.

Comment: can you also add your urls.py

Comment: is html differs from runserver or it is giving 404 error?

Comment: test-app/ is missing in urls.py

Comment: You don't include ``test-app`` part in ``urls.py``. This is because ``/test-app`` is the mount point in Apache and it is only what is after that which is passed through in ``PATH_INFO`` for routing. The problem is the lack of a handler for ``/`` itself. Use ``http://mypublicip/test-app/admin``, which does have a handler and you should get a response.

Comment: When using ``runserver`` it automatically hosts the static files. The Django documentation explains the need to host the static files separately if using a production grade WSGI server. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Comment: I also suggest you go back and read the Django documentation on how to add your handlers if you don't understand that much.